# Multi-armed Bandits

Tags: model-evaluation, notation, multiarmed-bandit

[image]

Could someone explains to me the notation of this function, I mean I understand that we take the average of sum of the rewards for some particular action, however the notation seems strange to me for example what is **t-1** at the top of the sigma notation, and what is this **1** there what does that suppose to mean

Comment: $i$ runs from $1$ to $t-1$ because it is "prior to $t$"

Comment: $\mathbb 1_{A_i=a}$ is $1$ when $A_i=a$ and $0$ when $A_i\not=a$

Comment: @Henry That sure looks like an answer to me!

Comment: Ok, I see now, so it is like if we say, consider only "the number of times a taken prior to t" and if we there is another action it should be zero. Ok thank you@Henry

Comment: Why is `sigma-algebra` tagged? Where's the measure theory in this question that requires it?

Answer (score 0):

*As requested in comments:*

- $i$ runs from $1$ to $t-1$  because it is "prior to $t$"
- $\mathbf{1}_{A_i=a}$ is $1$ when $A_i=a$ and $0$ when $A_i\not = a$